# Почему soup.find(id = 'productTitle') возвращает None, хотя элемент с таким id существует?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, bs4

Я хочу написать свой веб-скрапер на python. 
Вот мой код. print(soup.prettify()) работает правильно, но title почему-то возвращает None. Помогите найти ошибку.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Apple-iPhone-256GB-Silver-Unlocked/dp\
/B07PW3DC9L/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=iPhone+xs+max&qid=1564293888&s=gateway&sr=8-4'

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36\
 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.95"}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())

title = soup.find(id='productTitle')
print(title)
```

Comment: Думаю, что `soup.find( id = 'productTitle')` ничего не находит, потому что тег с этим `id` находится *вне* тега `html`, куда BeautifulSoup уже не смотрит.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов но он находится внутри, все в порядке.

Comment: @Andrey Я записал `soup.prettify()` в файл, поиск по файлу->`id="productTitle"` находится на 6532 строчке, `</html` на 806. Может, я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: @Andrey Хм. А когда просто `page.text` записал, то `id="productTitle"` находится раньше `</html`. Интересные дела.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, проблема в парсере `html`. Я попробовал использовать `lxml` парсер с вашим кодом и элемент успешно находится.

Измените одну строчку:

```
# lxml нужно предварительно установить
# pip install lxml

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
```

Comment: [Differences between parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)

Comment: C первым soup.find() ошибка исправлена, но со вторым все то же.Вот ссылка на этот вопрос.https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1007628/Последний-soup-find-почему-то-в-отличии-от-предыдущего-возвращает-none-хотя

Answer (score -2):

Во-первых, вместо “page” лучше использовать общепринятое «r»
Во-вторых, r.content используется, если что-то с кодировкой не так (не уверен, что правильно объяснил), вместо него используем r.text, который на входе даёт чистый HTML
Вот сам код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07PW3DC9L/'
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36/(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.95"}
r = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
title = soup.title
print(title.text)
```

Вывод;
Amazon.com: Apple iPhone Xs Max 6.5" 256GB Silver Unlocked SIM Free w/Free Case: Electronics

Если вы хотите избавиться от нежелательного “Amazon.com: ”, используйте срезы

Comment: Во-первых, Ваш код не компилируется. Во-вторых... - Достаточно! - сказал Наполеон

Comment: Ошибку исправил, @nomnoms12

Comment: Допустим, теперь этот код работает. Но как он отвечает на вопрос? Почему `find(id='productTitle')` возвращает `None`, когда элемент с таким `id` есть на странице? Вы взяли `title`, но вопрос не об этом.

Comment: JackWolf, спасибо, но этот способ работает только для заголовка. Если взять какой-либо другой елемент на странице, то soup.find() вернет None. На этом видео soup.find, почему-то, работает правильно. https://youtu.be/Bg9r_yLk7VY

Comment: @nomnoms12, в вопросе разговор шёл о заголовоке...

Comment: Я хотел взять данные именно из сайта, как в этом видео.youtu.be/Bg9r_yLk7VY