# Последний soup.find() почему-то, в отличии от предыдущего, возвращает None, хотя такой элемент есть на странцие

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://www.amazon.com/Apple-iPhone-GSM-Unlocked-64GB/dp/B077583FPX/ref=pd_cp_107_1?pd_rd_w=UVs7K&pf_rd_p=ef4dc990-a9ca-4945-ae0b-f8d5491\
98ed6&pf_rd_r=MH86W2EK\
G1T9T34QX5JR&pd_rd_r=1412d250-30bf-4016-bc3c-2eeb5dbb26bf&pd_rd_wg=tN82D&pd_rd_i=B077583FPX&psc=1&refRID=MH86W2EKG1T9T34QX5JR"
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36\
 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.95"}
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
title = soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text().strip()
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice")
print(price)
```

Comment: У меня нет такого элемента на странице. Открывал в браузере и проводил поиск по DOM.

Comment: Этот элемент есть в коде страницы, где цена указана красным.

Comment: Разве такое возможно, что элемент есть на странице, но его нет в парсе?

Comment: Покажи на скрине какой элемент именно нужен

Comment: Красные цифры возле написи Price возле картинки.Скрин отправить не могу.

Comment: Какая картинка??

Comment: Большая картинка iphone

Comment: Но я не вижу тут красной цены ниже да есть с надписью total price

Comment: Измените deliver to на Netherlands

Answer (score 2):

Такой элемент на сайте есть:

```
<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price
priceBlockBuyingPriceString">$309.99</span>
```

Но BeautifulSoup его не находит:

```
>>> price = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice')
>>> print(price)
None
```

Потому, что `priceblock_ourprice` элемент создаётся динамически при выполнении JavaScript, а `requests.get()` возвращает статический результат, то есть еще не измененный DOM до выполнения JavaScript.

Попробуйте например [requests-html](https://github.com/psf/requests-html). `render()` произведет подгрузку динамического контента:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(URL)
r.html.render()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```

Comment: это ответ или вопрос?

Comment: Это ответ. Не удалось наглядно показать на примере автора топика, т.к после рендер получаю капчу.